# how solve this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am trying to test my admin model with rspec but I am facing error how to solve this error please give me some idea.

my model/admin_spec.rb is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin do
  before do
    @admin = Admin.new(email: "superuser@superuser.com", hash: "iJXdppRiI52XsqJe", password: "736fc7f1f4f382e79f2278817d056a0ec14b9ff5", city_id: "", role_id: 4, request_hash: "", status: 1)
  end

  subject { @admin }

  it { should respond_to :email }
  it { should respond_to :password }
  it { should respond_to :phone }
  it { should be_valid }
end
```

And  the error is:

```
) Admin phone with valid format 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/admin_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 16.08 seconds
34 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/admin_spec.rb:15 # Admin phone with valid format 

Randomized with seed 31486
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a validation on the phone attribute of Admin but you never set it in your test subject.
Try setting it inside the before block with a valid phone attribute and the test should pass.

```
before do
    @admin = Admin.new(phone: "01234568", email: "superuser@superuser.com", hash: "iJXdppRiI52XsqJe", password: "736fc7f1f4f382e79f2278817d056a0ec14b9ff5", city_id: "", role_id: 4, request_hash: "", status: 1)
end
```

Comment: +1 Make sure the `phone` attribute is present **and formatted correctly**, otherwise you will continue to see the same error.